# How do I programatically test to see if github has my ssh key?

Tags: bash, github, ssh

I'm sure that I'm just having a bad day with bash.

I can't seem to get the exit code to properly compare in the if statement.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
echo "Testing to see if GitHub knows who $USER is"
$(ssh -T "git@github.com")
echo $? #just for debugging                                                                                                                                                                                    
# Github exit code of 1 indicates that we can connect and that they do not support shell access.                                                                                                               
# exit code of 255 indicates a ssh error, in this case we assume an invalid key                                                                                                                                
if [ "$?" != "1" ]; then
    echo "Add your SSH key to your Github account"
    echo "* Log into GitHub.com with your Github username and password and visit https://github.com/settings/ssh"
    echo "* Click Add SSH Key"
    echo "* Paste in the following under 'Key':"
    echo "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"
    echo "Press Enter when done."
    read
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `echo $?` is itself returning 0 and thus changing $?.   Take out your debug statement.

You also don't need quotes around $? or 1 in your conditional (it worked for me either way.)

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple like that.